# Create a Database Entry in Django Before Running Tests

Tags: database, django, unit-testing

I'm using Django 1.4 with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 13.04.  The Django project I'm working on has an entire test suite using Nose and Coverage.  I need to create a user in the database prior to any tests being run.  Where would I do this?

```
system_user = User(username=accounts_constants.SYSTEM_USER)
system_user.save()
```

The motivation for this stems from the existence of a "system robot" that handles a lot of the database transactions.  I have created a full tracking suite within our project.  If a user changes any sensitive information we track it.  If the system makes those changes we want the system user to be listed in the tracking information.

There are several places in the code that needed to be modified to support this change.  Obviously the test database doesn't have this user.  I would like to add it prior to any tests running (but after the database is created).

I've been digging around but can't see exactly where the database is created for testing purposes.  My first attempt was in the **init** of our test suite runner.

```
class CustomTestSuiteRunner(NoseTestSuiteRunner):
    """
    Runs testing suite and adds code coverage report.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomTestSuiteRunner, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.coverage = coverage.coverage()
        self.coverage.use_cache(0) # don't use caching with coverage.py
        system_user = User(username=accounts_constants.SYSTEM_USER)
        system_user.save()
```

This failed because it was still using the development database (the system user already exists on this database).

I tried adding the user further along in the testing sequence but can't seem to find where the appropriate place would be.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT1:

From girasquid's suggested solution:

I don't want to modify each `setUp` to super to the `CustomTestCase`.  Instead I am trying to do it in `__init__`.

```
class CustomTestCase(TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomTestCase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            system_user = User.objects.create(
                username=accounts_constants.SYSTEM_USER)
            system_user.save()
        except psycopg2.IntegrityError:
            pass
```

But I am getting an `IntegrityError` from `nose`.  Any ideas why this might be?

```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 518, in makeTest
    return self._makeTest(obj, parent)
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
```

EDIT2:

I was convinced by our team to implement a case-by-case setUp change to include the user rather than a system-wide change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would define [setUp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp)  on my test cases for this:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.system_user = User.objects.create(username=accounts_constants.SYSTEM_USER)
```

If you have a lot of test cases you need to do this for, it might be useful to put this on a base `TestCase` and then inherit from that for all your tests.

Comment: Yes, this what I was thinking - inheriting a base TestCase.  I was wondering if there was a better place to do it.  I'll probably do this.  Thanks.